# Combination of data from HashMaps java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

There are four HashMaps : AB, BA, BC and CB.

```
AB.put(A1, new String(){B1, B2});

BA.put(B1, new String(){A1});
BA.put(B2, new String(){A1});

BC.put(B1, new String(){C1});
BC.put(B3, new String(){C1});

CB.put(C1, new String(){B1});
CB.put(C1, new String(){B3});
```

Is there any algorithm to achieve the following combinations?

```
Input         Output
=====         =====
B, A, C         B1, A1, C1

A, B            A1, B1
                A1, B2

A, B, B         A1, B1, B1
                A1, B1, B2
                A1, B2, B1
                A1, B2, B2


A, C            A1, C1
```

Comment: *Is there any algorithm to achieve the following combinations?* Yes! You (presumably) wrote them using it.

Comment: You will need to be more clear on what the values are if you want someone to deduce the relationships. What is `BAC` for example? Also it usually helps to name things differently from objects of another type e.g., `A` and `B` are strings, `X` and `Y` are hashmaps. In your example, the reader sees the characters `A`, `B`, `C`, but it's not clear what is what here.

Comment: Is that supposed to be Java code up there?

Comment: @mvd, yeah, you are right and i have amended the input string. Basically the map is the relationship between input variables.

Comment: @Andreas, It is not necessarily to be in java. I am just wondering if there is an existing algorithm which i do not know to achieve this kind of output.

Comment: I can't make heads nor tails of this question. In your first code block, which I assume is supposed to be initializing the hashmaps from empty to populated, what does `new String(){B1, B2}` do? In your second code block, what does `A` (likewise `B` and `C`) mean? What does `,` mean?

Comment: After a bit more puzzling over this question, I have perhaps a bit more intelligent question, as well: is there a `BB` hashmap? If not, how did you arrive at the proposed output for input `A, B, B`?

Comment: @DanielWagner, lol. I am sorry if my question made you confused. There is no BB hashMap, as it should be driven from AB map.

Comment: @sky.flyer How should one decide whether to derive `BB` from `AB` or `CB`? How should it be derived once that decision is made?

Comment: @DanielWagner, for A, B, B, the possible maps should be AB, BB, AB. And this is what I found difficult to achieve. I am thinking of this to derive from the output of A, B.

Comment: @sky.flyer You give a lot of examples. But you don't say *why* you should get a particular output for a particular input. So it's really just impossible to figure out what's in your head.

Comment: well, likewise, that is all I have been given. And I need to find the solution. And anyway thanks for pop up.

Comment: @sky.flyer In that case, you definitely need to start a dialogue with whoever is expecting you to complete this task. If you can't understand what you're supposed to compute, you have almost no chance of finding a procedure for computing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: No.

For one, you haven't defined your rules.

What you are doing is kind of like a SQL join, where `B, A, C` means join from B to A to C, returning all permutations/combinations.

But what does `A, B, B` mean? Join from A to B to B, but there are no mapping from B to B, so result should be empty.

And `A, C`? There are no joins from A to C, so result should be empty.

But even if you define all that, since they are home-grown rules, you'll find no library implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your input and output aren't switched? How can one input have multiple outputs? It looks to me like you can map the outputs to the inputs by just stripping the numbers at the end e.g.,

```
A1, B1, B2 -> A, B, B
```

also

```
A1, B1, B1 -> A, B, B
```